# SQL query: get child values with comma separte value from mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2017. I have a mapping table with `parentId` with many `childId`'s. All Id's maps with parent table. I want to a query from mapping table childId with comma separate value in a row against parentId.

The query is

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT 
         CAST(b.ChildId as NVARCHAR(20)) + ',' 
     FROM 
         [std].[FieldMapping] b 
     WHERE 
         b.ParentId = a.FieldId) AS Childs 
FROM 
    [std].[Field] a 
WHERE 
    a.FieldId = 2080
```

But I get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How can I get my required result.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Why the sub-query? (Do a LEFT JOIN instead.)

Comment: LEFT JOIN can't provide my required result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [XML Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve this. Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/410ae/4)

```
SELECT a.name,
    (SELECT 
         CAST(b.name as NVARCHAR(20)) + ',' 
     FROM 
         child b 
     WHERE 
         b.Parent_Id = a.id
    FOR XML PATH('')) AS Childs 
FROM 
    parent a 
WHERE 
    a.id = 1
```

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim, Please check now. Added SQL Fiddle as well